# Node.js - Trying to understand singleton

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem with implementing Singleton pattern in my project, which runs on NodeJS (version 8 as far as I know). I created a Logger class, which I want to use whenever we want to log something to a console or database. Originally I implemented this as a Class like this:

```
class Logger {
    constructor() {
    }

    log() {
    }

    logToDatabase() {
    }

}

module.exports = new Logger()
```

And I was able to call `const logger = require('./Logger')` from other classes and use `logger.log()` function. I then did some research and found a post on StackOverflow where someone recommended to implement the module like this:

```
module.exports = {

  log: () => {
  },


  logToDatabase: () => {
  }

}
```

So I changed my code and everything (almost) is still working fine. I encountered the problem when I wanted to call `logger.log()` from another `.js` file (within their `module.exports` functions), like so:

another_file.js

```
const logger = require('./Logger')
module.exports = {

  foo: () => {
      logger.log()
  }
}
```

The error was `logger.log()` is not a function.

I managed to solve it by doing something like this:

```
var logger
module.exports = {

init: () => {
    logger = require('./Logger')
},

foo: () => {
    logger.log()
}
```

}

And I made sure that I call `init` function before I do any calls to `foo` in my main `index.js` file.

This seems to work fine now and I don't get any errors, but I want to make sure that I'm doing it the valid way, not by using some cheap hack that shouldn't work but appears to be fine. I would also like to understand why I encounter this issue (I imagine this may be caused by my lack of understanding how `module.exports` or `require` actually works. Am I right thinking this can be caused by using different modules? I got a "warning" in code saying we're using CommonJS, and it can be converted to ES6. I've heard about Babel which allows you to convert a code from one module to another (if I understand correctly), although this project ends in a week time and I would want to avoid using new things as much as possible.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The code youve shown works fine. Do you have any circular dependencies in it?

Comment: For a second I thought I do, but just checked and it doesn't seem like it. My `index.js` require `another_file.js`, `logger.js` and many others. `another_file.js` requires `logger.js` as well - but this should be fine. All my other files, which require `logger.js` are working without any issues. It's just that one file, where I'm trying to use `logger` inside `module.exports`